# Grunt / npm error on production server (Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, npm, ubuntu-14.04

I'm getting this error on the production server (local is fine both Windows and OSX)

```
/home/myuser/my-app/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/lib/findup-sync.js:33
}).flatten().uniq().value();
   ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.module.exports [as findup] (/home/myuser/my-app/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/lib/findup-sync.js:33:8)
    at Task.task.init (/home/myuser/my-app/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:427:16)
    at Object.grunt.tasks (/home/myuser/my-app/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:120:8)
    at Object.module.exports [as cli] (/home/myuser/my-app/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/cli.js:38:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt:45:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
```

So far I tried removing the node modules, clearing the cache and reinstalling but no success.

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean && npm install
```

I've also tried installing the module it's complains about:

```
 npm install findup-sync -g && npm link findup-sync
```

Also I've checked that my **.gitignore** file contains the **dist** folder

I'm going to paste my package.json and bower.json files any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

> package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.4.1",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-cli": "^0.1.13",
    "connect-modrewrite": "^0.8.2",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "^3.0.3",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^2.0.2 ",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "^1.0.3",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.8.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.13.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^0.9.4",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.11.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.9.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-filerev": "^2.3.1",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "^0.4.3",
    "grunt-newer": "^1.1.1",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-svgmin": "^2.0.1",
    "grunt-usemin": "^3.1.0",
    "grunt-wiredep": "^2.0.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.2.0",
    "time-grunt": "^1.2.1",
    "grunt-ng-constant": "^1.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "grunt-karma": "^0.12.0",
    "connect-livereload": "^0.5.3",
    "jshint-stylish": "^2.0.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.9",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.5",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.2.1",
    "phantomjs": "^1.9.18"
  }
}
```

> bower.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.3.0",
    "json3": "^3.3.0",
    "es5-shim": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass-official": "^3.3.5",
    "angular-animate": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-messages": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-touch": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.12.0",
    "font-awesome": "~4.2.0",
    "angular-progress-arc": "~1.0.0",
    "angular-xeditable": "~0.1.9",
    "angular-moment": "~0.10.1",
    "angular-native-picker": "~1.0.4",
    "angular-sweetalert": "~1.1.0",
    "angular-base64": "~2.0.5",
    "angular-timer": "~1.3.3",
    "angular-bootstrap-colorpicker": "~3.0.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.4.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you open up `/home/myuser/my-app/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/package.json` and see what the `version` attribute is, then compare that against what you're running locally/ on dev?

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your help, so if I look in that folder, I only have `findup-sync.js` in there, no `packages.json ` file.

Comment: I'm asking you to look in `/home/myuser/my-app/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/`, not `/home/myuser/my-app/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/lib/`.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that, here it is:
> local/dev
` "version" "0.1.3"`
> production
 
` "version": "0.2.1"`

Comment: It seems that somehow the wrong version of findup-sync has been installed by `npm`. Try `cd /home/myuser/my-app/node_modules/grunt/ && rm -rf node_modules/findup-sync && npm install findup-sync@0.1.3`.

Comment: thanks Matt, that worked, but now I get another grunt related error, which is weird because the file does exist, I've pasted the link to its contents bellow:
`>> Error: Unable to read "/home/myuser/my-app/node_modules/grunt-autoprefixer/package.json" file (Error code: undefined).
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.`


[package.json](https://gist.github.com/vasipuica/2961c7e7812b98b8b3de)

Comment: Can you run `npm -v` on both production and on dev? If production is running an older version than dev, run `sudo npm update -g npm@____` where `____` is the version that dev is running (e.g. if it's 2.5.1, run `sudo npm update -g npm@2.5.1`). Then try `rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean && npm install` from `/home/myuser/my-app/`.

Comment: They both run the same versions of node (v0.12.7) and npm (2.11.3), :(

Comment: Can you post the full error message you're getting (e.g. inc. the stack trace).

Comment: Sure, here you go [gist](https://gist.github.com/vasipuica/47a4eca6285170d3f386) . Btw Matt, thanks for all your patience and help.

Comment: Can you post `ls -al /home/myuser/myapp/node_modules/grunt-autoprefixer/package.json`, also, open `/home/myuser/myapp/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/file.js` and change `e.code` on line 247 to be `e.message` instead... then, re-run `grunt --verbose`, and paste the error message here.

Comment: this is the first `-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 1957 Sep  3 04:03 /home/myuser/myapp/node_modules/grunt-autoprefixer/package.json` and the [gist](https://gist.github.com/vasipuica/3cd10fe4ef7fa8668e92)

Comment: Your modules seem to be completely corrupted somehow... this particular error should be fixable by ensuring `/home/myuser/myapp/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/iconv-lite/encodings/table/gbk.js` is the same as [this](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite/blob/e559c6b9cbbdf1213ab65d9ed06a7626098d215f/encodings/table/gbk.js), but I'd then be worried you'll get another error, then *another* error. I'm at a loss as to how your modules have become so corrupted; especially if you've already cleaned them and tried a reinstall.

Comment: ... I would consider upgrading to the latest version of npm (`sudo npm install -g npm`), then `cd /home/myuser/my-app/ && rm -rf node_modules && npm install` again, in the hope that that will fix your issues... otherwise, I fear we'll be chasing errors around all day, none of which should exist in the first place; which is particularly worrying if this is going to be a production system.

Comment: thanks Matt, I shall do that,  to be fair this is another staging server but it should mimic the production on, so I'm going to reinstall node and npm and git it a try from there.

Comment: I'd be particularly interested to hear if a reinstall fixes the problem (or, what ends up fixing the problem, should you find a solution); do post a solution here if you find one!

Comment: I've posted my response bellow.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get to the bottom of it. A bit of background, I was experiencing this problem on a DigitalOcean droplet which was a 512M RAM/1 CPU.

Because of limited amount of RAM `npm install` used to fail / be killed **silently** so it wouldn't get the chances to finish installing and I wouldn't get an error / warning message either.

So in the end the solution was simple: increase the RAM and then run `-rf node_modules && npm cache clean && npm install` and it worked without any issues afterwards.

Hopefully some of you will find this helpful.

TL;DR; Try increasing your RAM size and then run `-rf node_modules && npm cache clean && npm install`